# Label invariance in definition of Product

Tags: logic, category-theory

**Label Invariance with respect to $f_1, f_2$ (Definition)**
Suppose ($A^2, p_1, p_2:A^2\rightarrow A$) is a binary product of objects $A\ and \ A$ in an arbitrary category $C$. Suppose $f_1, f_2:T\rightarrow A$ are maps in $C$. By definition of product,

$$\exists! f:T\rightarrow A_2 \ such \ that \ p_1\circ f=f_1 \wedge p_2\circ f=f_2.$$
We call definition of product label invariant with respect to $f_1, f_2$, if $\exists f' \ such \ that \ p_1 \circ f'=f_2 \wedge p_2\circ f'=f_1$. Because, otherwise two people can disagree on whether an object is a product if one labelled $f_1, f_2$ opposite to other person. Hence, the name label invariance.

**My question**:

Assuming the definition of a product as " In category $C$, an object $P$ together with maps $p_1:P\rightarrow A_1, p_2:P\rightarrow A_2$ is called product of objects $A_1, A_2$ if $\forall \ objects \ T \in C, \forall f_1:T\rightarrow A_1, \forall f_2:T\rightarrow A_2, \exists! f:T\rightarrow P$ such that $p_1\circ f=f_1 \wedge p_2\circ f=f_2$, if one can prove the label invariance, how?

Secondly, I think, this points at my ignorance of some general concept at play. So, I request you to be as general as possible.

Comment: Show that there is a natural isomorphism $\sigma_{A,B}:A\times B\cong B\times A$. If $(A\times B,\pi_1:A\times B\to A,\pi_2 : A\times B \to B)$ is a product of $A$ and $B$, show that $(B\times A,\pi_2\circ\sigma_{B,A},\pi_1\circ\sigma_{B,A})$ is also a product of $A$ and $B$. That is, they both satisfy the same universal property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing hard here at all.  Suppose $(P,p_1,p_2)$ is a product of objects $A_1=A$ and $A_2=A$.  Now suppose that $g_1:T\to A$ and $g_2:T\to A$ are two maps (these are the maps called $f_1$ and $f_2$ when proving label invariance, but I'm giving them different names to avoid confusion).  Our goal is to prove that there exists $f'$ such that $p_1\circ f'=g_2$ and $p_2\circ f'=g_1$.

How do we prove this?  Well, we just apply the definition of a product, with $f_1=g_2$ and $f_2=g_1$.  These maps $f_1$ and $f_2$ are indeed maps $T\to A_1=A$ and $T\to A_2=A$, so the definition applies and says there exists a unique $f:T\to P$ such that $p_1\circ f=f_1=g_2$ and $p_2\circ f=f_2=g_1$.  So, if we take $f'=f$, we're done.

The key point here is that the definition of a product says "for all $f_1$ and $f_2$".  So in that definition, $f_1$ and $f_2$ are just placeholder variables, which could refer to any two maps $T\to A_1$ and $T\to A_2$ at all.  In particular, you could let $f_1$ refer to the map "$f_2$" in the statement of label invariance and let $f_2$ refer to the map "$f_1$" in the statement of label invariance.  (But, to avoid horribly confusing yourself, I recommend renaming one of these sets of variables, like I did with $g_1$ and $g_2$ above.)

Comment: Ah! I did not see $f_1, f_2$ in definition as reference to some maps (I think it might be true in general, that objects are "referred to" in definitions) , and I totally ignored the symbol $\forall$. I appreciate your clear response.